# Weird right alignment/flipping issue with some applications in Kubuntu 20.04

Tags: 20.04, kubuntu, themes, gtk

The issue I am facing is that some apps (I suspect GTK apps) are right aligned.

The issue with gimp (snap package):

[image: Gimp menus are right aligned, and the position of toolboxes seem like mirrors of the way vanilla gimp works.]

Flatseal:
[image: Flatseal's menu has gone to the right side.]

Then there's the issue with cursors in dialogboxes that start from the right-side by default:

[image: Latte Dock. As you can see, the placeholder is gone to the right of the text box.]

Comment: This appears like a tweaked system. You will need to carefully check all the tweaks you have done to identify which one is causing the issue.

Comment: @vanadium The only tweak i have done is using latte-dock.:-/

Comment: @Someone it's Sweet's plasma style yes.

Comment: Please, change it back to Breeze! Also, select the option "use desktop layout from theme"

Comment: @Someone thank you, now it's fixed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to change your desktop theme back to the default Breeze theme. The current GTK theme you're using is producing this unwanted behaviour.

1. Open the Settings app in KDE Plasma:

   [image: KDE Settings]
2. Navigate to *Appearance* → *Global Themes*:

   [image: Global Themes]
3. Select the *Breeze* theme:

   [image: Breeze theme selection]
4. Click on *Apply*:

   [image: Apply changes]
5. Log out and log in again.

That's it!
Good Luck!

Answer (score 0):

By the recommendation of [Someone](https://askubuntu.com/a/1385588/1460940), I reverted the plasma themes and used a vanilla theme. Apparently, the Sweet Mars theme had some problems with GTK apps.
Now it's fixed.